# IceFaces and PrimeFaces portlets on the same Liferay page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, liferay-6, icefaces

I have portlets written on IceFaces 1.8.2.
Since I found PrimeFaces better I decided to write my new portlet with JSF2 and PrimeFaces 3.5.

Separately everything is working. But when I'm trying to put my PrimeFaces portlet and IceFaces portlet on one page PrimeFaces doesn't work.

UI is more or less alright, but there are a lot of mistakes in javascript.

Can I solve this problem somehow?

I'm using Liferay 6.0.6

Comment: Can you include what type of javascript-errors are you facing? You can find out the errors through [**firebug add-on**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/) of Mozilla Firefox browser.

Comment: for example when I want to use p:dialog with widgetVar="myDialog" and I open it with myDialog.show(); I have error that myDialog.show() is not defined

Comment: This will be very hard to fix, as both ICEfaces and PrimeFaces use jQuery as underlying Javascript library. I've never seen this work before. Migrating the existing ICEfaces portlet is not an option?

Comment: Are you facing something like that with on lifray 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264774/icefaces-application-not-working-with-liferay-portal-on-weblogic

Answer (score 0):

## Do not include Primefaces and Icefaces portlets on the same portal page!

Since they both rely on jQuery, they will both include (potentially different versions of) jQuery on the page which will cause javascript  conflicts. There may be workarounds for this (although I don't know of any), but it is an extremely bad idea.